# Azure DevOps: Track build status for commits in mutliple repositories pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have a **multi-repo pipeline**

Can azure track build status for commits for repositories other than the self repo that contains the azure-pipelines.yaml file?

When a commit is built in another pipeline status badge is not shown. It seems the build is linked to the last commit of the self repo instead of the triggering repo

I don't know how to modify this behaviour and I'm expect that the build is linked to the commit that trigger the pipeline (commit of another repo).

Comment: Hi there, have you got a chance to check my answer below? If the information can resolved your query, you may consider marking the answer to help others with similar concerns. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

The build status badge is displayed because by default, the option to `Report build status` is enabled for a YAML pipeline; and this option will have the badge displayed on the source repository instead of the repository resource that triggers the pipeline.

[image]

For this, you can suggest a [feature request](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=21&entry=suggestion) to display the build status badge on all repository resources. As of now, you may also consider the workaround to [add a status badge to your repository](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/create-first-pipeline?view=azure-devops&preserve-view=true&tabs=java%2Ctfs-2018-2%2Cbrowser#add-a-status-badge-to-your-repository) Readme.md with the help of the badge Markdown.

Hope the information would be helpful.